# Subclass Eigen types

Tags: c++, geometry, eigen

I'm looking for some library for some 2D and 3D linear geometry operation (intersection between 2D lines, between 3D lines and plane, stuffs like that) and I ran into [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) that seems cool-and-fast, scalable, easy to include, multiplatform, etc..

I am used to think about 2/3D geometry in vectors with x,y,z property and with Eigen datatypes I don't find them:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"

...

Eigen::Vector2d p1;
double x = p1[0];
double y = p1[1];
```

For my personal convenience I would like to subclass Vector2d adding some comfortable methods like

```
Vec2D::x() { return this[0]; }
Vec2D::set(double x, double y) { this[0]=x; this[1]=y; }
....
```

Or similar methods. I am not a c++ experienced programmer so I'm asking if this is the right way, and how to handle templates..

Comment: Have you checked out boost.geometry? It's a great library for geometrical computations! If you need 3D stuff, try CGAL as well.

Comment: yeah I've seen but Eigen seems more easy to intall in multiplatform and lighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Vector2d` in Eigen already has these methods:

```
const T& x();
T& x();
const T& y();
T& y();
```

All exist for `Vector2d`. Since they return references, you can use this for setting values as well:

```
Eigen::Vector2d v2d;
v2d.x() = 1; 
v2d.y() = 2;
```

See the Eigen documentation [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/1/classEigen_1_1VectorBase.html#d0bd962a702d18fa55e1a95435b1a39e).

Comment: ohu, why aren't they in the QTCreator method summary advice?